# accessing php variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've done created a webpage, set up appache2 on ubuntu server so I can view this page over the internet. I've installed php5 and MySQL and would like to access information in the database on the webpage that I've created.

Right now, I've got a file *test.php* that accesses the database and puts some of the information into variables. I've scripted using javascript something that will change the webpage content at the click of a button.

Now, the webpage crashes whenever the button is pushed as it says the variables are undefined or null references. Fair enough, but my question is how does one access variables on a .php file through the webpage? Can a browser use information in the .php file if I script it into the page?

I was told that the php file would be parsed automatically. I'm guessing that server side this page is being accessed but I can use it through web browser.

Edit:

```
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($grab);
$name = $row["name"];
$color = $row["color"];
$price = $row["price"];
$n1 = $name[0];
$c1 = $color[0];
$p1 = $price[0];

?>
```

Ok so I changed the php file to this, so now all it is doing is defining variables. I installed a couple of MySQL mods and no problems now.

next issue is how do I get use php variables in javascript

```
function load(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatecahnge = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML = "<?php echo $n1;?>;
         }
      }
   }
```

So onload this ajax function should run and change itemNameLink1 to the php variable $n1, only it doesn't and I just get an empty string. Everything should be set up right but using the php variable seems impossible. would it be any easier with the jquery get command, I'm guessing that unless I sort this out I'm gonna struggle.

I'm also assuming a few things, I've checked error logs and the php file is active assuming I've connected right it should be accessing the database. I'm very new so I do not know how to test this.

I'm also assuming that when php file is in the server webpage file directory. that it is automatically working. again very new to setting up a server so using ubuntu server and being familiar with all the commands that I need to use or how apache2 operates is difficult for me.

Comment: PHP runs on server, and JavaScript on client. You can't access PHP variable using JavaScript...

Comment: that's what I was thinking, is there another way to access database records client side

Comment: If you are looking to get information without reloading the page, then we are talking AJAX

Answer (score 0):

PHP Is executed on the server, your client receives the result as a plain text/html document. 
Your browser runs the javascript when it received the plain document, so you can't access PHP vars directly with javascript. 
But you could set javascript variables when the page is generated on the server like this

```
<?php $myPhpVar = 'Hello World'; ?>
<script>
  //This line would result in  var test = "Hello World";  when send to client
  var test = "<?=$myPhpVar?>"; 
  alert(test);
</script>
```

Furthermore you can execute requests to your server with javascript (so you can read the result from test2.php as example, and use that somewhere on your page). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Pure javascript:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
    if (this.readyState === DONE){
        alert(this.readyState);
    }
};
var action = 'doSomethingOnServer';
request.open('GET', 'test2.php?action=' + action, true); 
request.send(null);
```

Jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
<script>
var action = 'doSomethingOnServer';
$.ajax({
  url: "test2.php?action=" + action,
}).done(function(result) {
  alert(result);
});
<script>
```

For testing if your php works on your server create a file  info.php (or something).  and add this to the file

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you access that page you should get a page with a lot of information about your php configuration.
I'm not sure how you did install your php, but on a development machine you can change a few things in your php.ini that makes life easier

```
display_startup_errors = 1
display_errors = 1
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting when you change your php.ini don't forget to restart your apache

JSON Example:

data.php

```
<?php
    $db_result = array(array('name' => 'record1'), array('name' => 'record2'));
    echo json_encode($db_result);
?>
```

index.php

```
<script>
$.ajax({url: 'data.php', dataType: 'json'}).done(function(result) { 
  //result = an object from your database (in this case an array with objects with the property name)
  alert(result);  
  alert(result[0].name);
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks that was very helpful I've done some of it but the rest was really helpful.

Comment: actually thinking about it, what I've got is a .php file retrieving some data from a database, saying it receives it in plain text is it not possible to read the data from the database that has been retrieved onto the .php file say if I echo the results of searching the database on the .php file. could I not then use that data in the browser.

Comment: Json is your friend here, i'm updating the answer soon with an example

Comment: this sounds great I'll have to change a bit but I read somewhere of a jquery way of getting data sounds like the way to go

Comment: instead of using index.php can it just be in a plain html document. I mean because my webpage is on a html page.

Comment: yes you can, as long as you don't use php on that page